# Nginx + Apache2 response 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: laravel, apache, nginx, yii2, nginx-reverse-proxy

Such situation.

There are two sites: site.ru and admin.site.ru
Hung on one ip

site.ru is made in yii2
admin.site.ru is made in laravel

Nginx + Apache2 bundle configured

Apache2 configurations:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/site.ru

    ServerName site.ru

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/privkey.pem
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/chain.pem

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/site.ru>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:8083>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/admin.site.ru/public

    ServerName admin.site.ru

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.site.ru/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.site.ru/privkey.pem
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.site.ru/chain.pem

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/admin.site.ru>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

nginx configuration

```
server { 
 listen 80 default_server; 
 listen [::]:80 default_server; 
 return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
 listen 443 ssl http2;
 listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

 ssl on;
 ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.site.ru/fullchain.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.site.ru/privkey.pem; 

 root /var/www/admin.site.ru/public;
 index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
 server_name admin.site.ru;

 location / {
      proxy_pass https://{IP_SERVER}:8083;
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /nginx_static_files;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 }

 location /nginx_static_files/ {
      alias /var/www/admin.site.ru/;
      internal;
 }

 location ~ /(\.ht|\.user\.ini) {
      deny all;
 }
}

server {
 listen 443 ssl http2;
 listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

 ssl on;
 # ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem;
 # ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key;
 ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/fullchain.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/privkey.pem; 

 root /var/www/site.ru;
 index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
 server_name site.ru;

 location / {
      proxy_pass https://{IP_SERVER}:8081;
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /nginx_static_files;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 }

 location /nginx_static_files/ {
      alias /var/www/site.ru/;
      internal;
 }

 location ~ /(\.ht|\.user\.ini) {
      deny all;
 }
}
```

As a result: site.ru - works fine, but admin.site.ru - issues 502 Bad Gateway

Tell me, please, what could be the problem?

Comment: how does proxy pass https know to send to 8081 vs 8083 in nginx config?

Answer (score 0):

Your subdomain should have separate vhosts conf for SSL and non SSL. And in my experience if you are using NGINX as reverse proxy you should only change Laravel root folder in Apache vhost conf.

But probably in your nginx conf this lines should be:

```
 root /var/www/admin.site.ru;
 index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
 server_name admin.site.ru;
```

and in Apache too. I see in your Apache conf, site.ru instead of admin.site.ru